# Anyone have an idea of what percentage of Android devices support NEON?

Tags: android, neon

Simple enough right? Can't seem to find some canonical study.

Comment: SO != Study Organization

Comment: The question is very interesting indeed, but it's definitely out of the scope of SO. Btw, I think you may find such information from companies like Gartner or others, who make market studies, but I doubt this is something you can get without money

Comment: Similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067039/what-share-of-android-devices-benefits-from-libjpeg-turbo-optimisations/9067995#9067995

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Android phones that have come out in the US since 2011 seem to have NEON available.  The fragmentation of the market, however, means you'll almost certainly need to do feature testing before attempting to use it.  Luckily there's simple example code for that that comes with the Android NDK.

Sorry I don't have an exact percentage, then again you didn't specify a specific market, or what years you're talking about.